# A simple C code compile and run successfully in Borland Turbo C++ compiler but show errors in other compiler

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have run the following code in Borland Turbo C++ and can run successfully:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a;
    int& b=a;
    a=10;
    printf("%d",a);
    return 0;

}
```

But when I try to run it in code block or visual studio or dev C++ I get the following error message:

[Error] expected identifier or '(' before '&' token

I would like to use code block or visual studio but I can not fix up this error. What is the wrong am I doing.

(My apologies if this post sounds silly/stupid. I thought I'd ask here. Ignoring these core bits never made anyone a better programmer.)

Thanks everyone.

Comment: That's not C.  It's C++ (the `printf` crap notwithstanding).  C doesn't understand references.

Comment: @KarthikKalyanasundaram: Even if you save the file with a `.c` extension?

Comment: Yes, I saved the file as .c extension. Thanks dear I got the solution. I did not know reference was not a concept of C but C++. Thanks again.

Comment: @cHao Sorry I overlooked. I thought I deleted the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you are trying to compile it using C compiler.
Try with C++ compiler like g++ it works!

Comment: Thanks sakura to response.If I want to use visual studio 2010 to run c programming code what should I do? visual studio is a nice tool, it runs all C code except reference variable of C. what additional configuration should be done to run this code in visual studio 2010.

Comment: @sattar_kuet.bd: VS is a C++ compiler.  Frankly, it sucks at modern C, and last i heard, they don't plan on remedying that.